# Can my app support Split View on the iPad Pro, but not the iPad Air 2?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios9, splitview

(Note that this question refers to the Split View multitasking introduced in iOS 9, not the Split View Controller.)

Our app's user interface is relatively restricted, and wouldn't work well with Split View on a regular-sized iPad - we can't shrink the screen easily. However, the new iPad Pro allows you to do Split View with two full-sized iPad apps on screen at once.

Is it possible for us to support Split View under the iPad Pro (where our app will still be big enough to show its whole UI), but not under the iPad Air 2 (where the view would be too cramped to show the whole UI)?

Comment: No, because split view multitasking always for "window" resizing, even if this were allowed the results would be undesirable. If your app doesn't support all size classes, then allowing split view multitasking is not advised. For more information about multitasking on the iPad watch this video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-205/